# How to append numpy ndarray (images) to get similar dataset like mnist

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, mnist

```
enter code here
img = cv2.imread(f'resized_data/train/normal/IM-0115-0001.jpeg')
img2 = cv2.imread(f'resized_data/train/normal/IM-0117-0001.jpeg')



imgs = []
imgs.append(img)
imgs.append(img2)

imgs = np.array(imgs)
```

So I have two numpy.ndarray so far, with the shape of (256, 256, 3) each.
I append them to a list, which I will convert to a numpy ndarray later. When I call the imgs.shape function the shape is the following --> (2, ).
Why is the shape of the imgs array (2, ) and not (2, 256, 256, 3) ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `img_to_array` exactly do? Does it flatten the array?

Comment: Sorry I should edit it out, that remained in it, or should be commented out.

Comment: Not actually a `tensorflow` or `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `opencv`).

Comment: Have you checked that if both of their sizes are equal? I know you've mentioned it in your post, but I still suspect it. And check if they are the same type? like one might be float one might be int or something.

Comment: Both of them are uint8, and both have (256, 256, 3) as shape, I checked it. I'll create a custom ndarray just to check again and be sure, bcs you might be onto someting.

Comment: It showed the dimensions were the same, but when I resized them again to (255, 255),  it worked correctly. Looks like my resize algorithm didn't round correctly or there were some problem with it, but thanks anyway!